# Lightbox change image programmatically

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I use this lightbox-plugin: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ how can I change the image src programmatically so that the plugin calculates the width and hight dynamically? To trigger the click method isn't a solution for me, because I have a swipe-event on the lightbox-image so when I swipe the image gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Target your element what you want to manipulate, and after change the `src` attribute of it:

```
document.getElementById('imageElementId').src = 'http://example.org/logo.jpg';
```

Reference from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp).

Your image element need an id, wrote that id where I wrote `imageElementId` and change the URL of the picture  to your picures URL.

**UPDATE**

I've checked the lightbox plugin there is no `id` for the image. You can use, `document.getElementsByClassName('lb-image')[0].src;` to target the image.

Comment: this works for sure, but the lightbox-container is out of shape... this was my question how to fix this

Comment: What do you mean out of shape? See my updated answher.